# How to find out the real part of this.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have to sum this:

$$S:=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{M+1}\right)+\dots+\cos\left(\frac{M\pi}{M+1}\right)$$

Where $M$ is a given natural number.

I tried with this:

Since $$e^{i a}=\cos a+i\sin a$$

and put this in our situation we have:

$$e^{i\frac{\pi}{M+1}}=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{M+1}\right)+i \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{M+1}\right)$$

If we use this geometric sum:

$$e^{\frac{i\pi}{M+1}}+...+e^{\frac{i M\pi}{M+1}}=\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi}{M+1}}(e^{\frac{i\pi M}{M+1}}-1)}{e^{\frac{i\pi}{M+1}}-1}=:A$$

Then we have that $$S={\rm Re}A$$

Questions:

1) Are this steps well done?

2) Help me to find out ${\rm Re}A$, please!

Comment: How did you get the second formula for A (the one which is a ratio)?

Comment: Corrected (removed) $(k+l)$ from the problem to simplify the question.

Comment: Since you changed your post, remove $k$ and $l$ from the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1+S=\sum_{k=0}^M\cos\frac{\pi k}{M+1}={\rm Re}\sum_{k=0}^Me^\frac{\pi k}{M+1}={\rm Re}\frac{e^{i\pi}-1}{e^{i\pi/(M+1)}-1}=0.$$
Thus, $S=-1.$

Comment: How do you know $Re \frac{e^{i\pi-1}}{e^{i\pi/(M+1)}-1}=0$

Why $e^{i \pi/(M+1)}-1$ is never $0$?

Comment: The formula for the sum is not $\frac{e^{i \pi \frac{M+1}{M+1}}-e^{\frac{i\pi}{M+1}}}{e^{\frac{i\pi}{M+1}}-1}$?

Comment: @MathsStudent: $e^{i\pi/(M+1)}\ne -1$ since (for example) $${\rm Re}e^{i\pi/(M+1)}=\cos\frac{\pi}{M+1}\ge\cos\frac{\pi}{2}=0,$$ but ${\rm Re}(-1)=-1.$

Comment: @MathsStudent: The formula that you wrote is for the sum when $k$ changes from $\underline{1}$ to $M$, but in solution it's from $\underline{0}$ to $M$.

Answer (score 0):

1) Steps are correct.

2) **Hint:** The values are roots of unity, and satisfy the equation $ x^{M+1} -1 = 0 $.
By Vieta's, the sum of all the roots will be 0 (for $M \geq 1$).
There are $M+1$ roots of unity, but we only have $M$ values, so which root is missing?
Hence, what is the sum of our $M$ values?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply
$$
\cos a+\cos 2a+\cos 3a+...+\cos(Na)
$$
with $2\sin b$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N 2\sin b\cos ka=\sum_{k=1}^N (\sin(ka+b)-\sin(ka-b))
$$
Using either $b=a$ or better $b=\frac a2$, you get a cancellation of inner terms, in other words, a telescoping sum.

---

To the original question, how to make the denominator real,
$$
\frac{e^{ia}-1}{e^{ib}-1}
=\frac{e^{ia/2}}{e^{ib/2}}
      \frac{e^{ia/2}-e^{-ia/2}}{e^{ib/2}-e^{-ib/2}}
=e^{i(a-b)/2}\frac{\sin(a/2)}{\sin(b/2)}
$$